# Is there any international convention/treaty/protocol that regulates how a country should behave if a nuclear incident happens on its territory?

Tags: international-relations, nuclear-weapons, nuclear-energy

There is [a quite a long list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_power_accidents_by_country#Russia) of nuclear power and radioactive incidents that happened after nuclear power has been discovered. One of the most recent was the [Nyonoksa radiation accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyonoksa_radiation_accident) that happened in Russia when the authorities delayed official confirmation:

> Although initially denied, involvement of radioactive materials in the
>   accident was later confirmed by Russian officials

Since radioactive incidents might easily affect the neighboring countries I am wondering if there is any convention related to informing the countries that might be affected by such an incident so that they can act accordingly.

**Question:** Is there any international convention/treaty/protocol that regulates how a country should behave if a nuclear incident happens on its territory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but not all nations are signatories. Here is a [list of incidents](https://www-news.iaea.org/) reported to IAEA.

As of this writing, recent incidents include

- workers contaminated in Australia,
- theft of a radiation source after a vehicle accident in India,
- problems detected with emergency diesel generators in France,
- overexposure of a worker in France,
- overexposure of two workers in Iran.